# Como evitar redirección de url mediante petición con curl?

Tags: php, curl

Buenos días estoy realizando un scarp a una página web para lo cual me traigo el contenido de dicha página --"https://www.fossil.com/us/en/search.ES3565.html"-- el problema es que cuando realizo la petición ya sea con curl o con una libreria para está tarea, la url me redirecciona a la página oficial de la región, digo esto porque usando un navegador como tor la url me lleva precisamente a lo que necesito. La página oficial de USA, pero si lo hago en google o firefox me redirecciona a la web oficial de la región, Colombia en este caso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso realizo la busqueda con TOR y el navegador me devuelve lo que necesito la página oficial USA de fossil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que obtengo desde un navegador como chrome o firefox, el problema es que cuando hago un curl o scrap con la libreria shd.php que es la que siempre he usado en estos casos, la respuesta es la redirección local, en caso de la libreria o un 301 Moved permanently en caso de hacerse la petición con curl.

```
<?php
namespace Utils;

/**
 * Helpers functions class
 * @author Camilo Martinez eliascamiloms92@gmail.com
 */
abstract class Helpers {

  /**
   * Configuration for curl
   * @var array
   */
  protected static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true, //Está opción fue agregada temporalmente 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, //Está opción fue agregada temporalmente
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60
  );

  /**
   * Execute GET request
   * @param  string  $path Path for request
   * @param  array $params Request params
   * @param  boolean $assoc
   * @return array Request response
   */
  public static function get($path, $params = null, $assoc = false) {
    $exec = self::execute($path, null, $params, $assoc);
    return $exec;
  }

  /**
   * Execute POST request
   * @param  string $path Path for request
   * @param  array $body Body request
   * @param  array  $params Request params
   * @return array Request response
   */
  public static function post($path, $body = null, $params = array(), $httpHeaders = array()) {
    $body = json_encode($body);
    if(empty($httpHeaders))
      $httpHeaders[] = 'content-type: application/json';
    $opts = array(
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $httpHeaders,
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body
    );

    $exec = self::execute($path, $opts, $params);
    return $exec;
  }

  /**
   * Execute curl Request
   * @param  string $path Path for request
   * @param  array  $opts [description]
   * @return array Response of request
   */
  protected static function execute($path, $opts = array(), $params = array(), $assoc = false) {
    $uri = self::make_path($path, $params);
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, self::$CURL_OPTS);
    if(!empty($opts)){
      curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
    }
    $exec = curl_exec($ch);
    $return['body'] = (is_array(json_decode($exec, true)) || is_object(json_decode($exec, true))) ? json_decode(curl_exec($ch), $assoc):$exec;
    $return['error'] = curl_error($ch);
    $return['errno'] = curl_errno($ch);
    $return['httpCode'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return;
  }

  /**
   * Build uri
   * @param  string $path
   * @param  array  $params Query parameters
   * @return string Uri
   */
  protected static function make_path($path, $params = array()) {
    $uri = $path;
    if(!empty($params)) {
      $paramsJoined = array();
      foreach($params as $param => $value) {
       $paramsJoined[] = "$param=$value";
      }
      $params = '?' . implode('&', $paramsJoined);
      $uri = $uri . $params;
    }
    return $uri;
  }
}
```

Esta es una clase con la que hago peticiones curl.

```
$response = hps::get('https://www.fossil.com/us/en/search.ES3565.html');
var_dump($response);
```

La pregunta es existe alguna forma de evitar la redirección y que obtenga directamente lo que necesito?

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=0 deberia evitar redirecciones

Comment: Cuando hago la petición este valor esta en 0. Aunque evita que se redireccione sigo obteniendo un 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently.

Comment: Parece que te redirigen en función de la geolocalización. La única solución sería usar un proxy/VPN para que evitar que detecten que la petición llega desde Colombia

Comment: Exacto eso es al parecer lo que sucede, a decir verdad no se muy bien como usar un proxy y menos si existe alguna forma de hacerlo con php.

Comment: Para usar un proxy con curl en php lo pones en CURLOPT_PROXY, hay muchas páginas donde encontrar proxys gratuitos (busca free-proxy-list por ejemplo) para probar

Comment: Gracias voy a probar para ver si funciona

Comment: Gracias use un proxy gratuito un poco lento pero funciona... de verdad muchas Gracias.

Comment: `protected static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    // CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    // CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0,
    CURLOPT_PROXY => '81.5.119.67',
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => '45694',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60
  );` Asi quedaron las opciones del request por si alguien alguna vez necesita algo similar.

Answer (score 1):

puedes establecer estos parametros:

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0
```

Comment: Si el paramtetro `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` esta en true, para el `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` que aunque esta ahora en true ya tenia el valor false y aun así sigo obteniendo un 301 y/o la pagina local.

Comment: me devuelve todo bien con los parametros mas basicos! intenta eliminando el 'content-type: application/json';

Comment: Si te fijas en la función get no seteo ningún content-type, esto lo hago con la funcion post. el get se va con los parametros basicos que estan en la variable `$CURL_OPTS`